# Eclipse binding SWT button selection to a model function

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I've been learning some eclipse data binding, it's been fairly simple to bind data from a model to the UI. What I'm wondering is if there is some way to bind the selection (event?) on an SWT button, or combobox, etc. to a method on my model.

I've just been manually creating a connection using `addSelectionListener` in my window code which simply calls the function on my model object.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not. Databinding is to synchronize values between different objects.

What you can do is to bind the boolean select-state of a widget to a property (not a method) in your model. For example:

```
// observe the widget
ISWTObservableValue uiObs = WidgetProperties.selection().observe(myButton);
// observe the 'selected' property of 'myObject'
IObservableValue modelObs = BeansObservables.observeValue(myObject, "selected");
// bind
ctx.bindValue(uiObs,modelObs);
```